# Converting Multiple xts objects to multiple data.frames in r

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I am trying to convert multiple xts objects in the Global environment to be multiple data.frames of the same name. I am trying to create a array of data.frames that can be feed into a program.

My code creates the xts objects OK but I would have to go back an manually convert each xts object for example  (`LMT <- as.data.frame(LMT)`). I am looking to do a 100 or stocks at a time so this would be a great time saver.  I was able to create its stock its objects for the example below in the list for tickers.

My code is as follows

```
require(quantmod)
require(xts)
tickers <- c("REGN", "LMT", "ZN", "OXY", "PG", "WBA", "EXC")     

FromDate = "2011-01-01"
ToDate = "2015-08-07" #Set one day ahead 
getSymbols(tickers, from = FromDate, to = ToDate,  src="yahoo")
###Convert to Data Frame
stocks[ticker] <- as.data.frame (c("REGN", "LMT", "ZN", "OXY", "PG", "WBA", "EXC")
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `getSymbols` create objects in the global environment, create a new environment and tell `getSymbols` to create objects there.

```
require(quantmod)
tickers <- c("REGN", "LMT", "ZN", "OXY", "PG", "WBA", "EXC")     
dataEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(tickers, from="2011-01-01", to="2015-08-07",  env=dataEnv)
```

Then you can use `eapply` to loop over all the objects in the new environment and apply a function to them, returning a list.

```
stocks <- eapply(dataEnv, as.data.frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the `tidyquant` package to solve this problem. You can supply the tickers to the `tq_get()` function, which will return one data frame with all the prices in. You can do this with as many stock symbols as you would like.

```
library(tidyquant)
tickers <- c("REGN", "LMT", "ZN", "OXY", "PG", "WBA", "EXC")
tickers %>%
    tq_get(get  = "stock.prices",
           from = "2011-01-01",
           to   = "2015-08-07")
```

If you'd like to perform with an index or exchange, `tidyquant` has `tq_index()` and `tq_exchange()` which can be piped (`%>%`) to `tq_get`. For example, you could do this to get all of the stocks in the S&P500:

```
tq_index("SP500") %>%
    tq_get(get  = "stock.prices"
           from = "2011-01-01",
           to   = "2015-08-07")
```

Comment: I tried this and got error.  
tq_exchange("NYSE") %>%
  tq_get(get  = "stock.prices",
         from = "2011-01-01",
         to   = "2015-08-07")
The error message is: Column `Symbol` doesn't exist.

Comment: NASDAQ changed their site. I haven't had time to make (yet another) update, but there is a solution forthcoming. https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant/issues/190

Comment: Thanks!  I followed the github link you provided.  For now will use the json solution.  Until tq_exchange() is updated.