# Converting Multiple existing xts objects to multiple data.frames

Tags: r, loops, data-conversion

There is already a thread asking how to convert multiple `xts` objects into as many data.frames [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32343001/2950721). Unfortunately, the solutions show how to do it for data that is being downloaded in `.GlobalEnv`. Moreover, the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366098/2950721) of mentioned thread suggests to create a new environment, download the objects into it, and transform everything inside with the following code: `stocks <- eapply(dataEnv, as.data.frame)`.

However, this creates a large list stored in the variable `stocks`, whereas I need the objects to remain discrete. Even when I run the code without generating a list (i.e., by just applying `eapply(dataEnv, as.data.frame)`), nothing happens. This has been documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69227012/2950721). In order to update the original object, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227029/2950721) to this question was to use a code that looks like this: `NKLA <- fortify.zoo(NKLA)`. This solution, which by the way works, is ok for a few objects that can be done manually and I need to automatise the process.

In my case, the objects are already downloaded and some of the them are `data.frames`, some are `xts` objects, and there might even be other objects.

What I need is to find the `xts` objects and transform them into `data.frames`.

In order to find the `xts` objects, I use the following code: `xtsObjects <- which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts)))`, but applying `xtsObjects <- fortify.zoo(xtsObjects)` only creates yet another object called `xtsObjects` that contains, for example, 2 obs. of 2 variables (because there are 2 `xts` objects in the environment).

For example, the following code (which should be reproducible) does not change the discrete `xts` objects into discrete `data.frames`:

```
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)
tickers <- c("TSLA", "RMO", "TSM", "PDD")
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers, auto.assign = TRUE, env = globalenv())

xtsObjects <- which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts)))

# This does not do anything:
for (i in 1:length(xtsObjects)) fortify.zoo(xtsObjects[i])
```

My question:

- What loop (or any code) could I use in order to simultaneously update the original already loaded/existing `xts` objects into `data.frame` objects?

---

System used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping with `which`, it just returns the position with the `names` of the objects and not the actual objects.  We may need to `get` the value of the objects with the `names` from that 'xtsObjects' output (`mget` - returns the values of multiple objects in a `list`, then loop over the `list` with `map` and convert to `data.frame`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- mget(names(xtsObjects)) %>% 
      map(fortify.zoo)
```

-output

```
> str(out)
List of 4
 $ PDD :'data.frame':   793 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Index       : Date[1:793], format: "2018-07-26" "2018-07-27" "2018-07-30" "2018-07-31" ...
  ..$ PDD.Open    : num [1:793] 26.5 27.5 23.3 22.2 19.4 ...
  ..$ PDD.High    : num [1:793] 27.5 27.5 23.9 22.7 21.4 ...
  ..$ PDD.Low     : num [1:793] 25 23.2 21.9 19.6 18.6 ...
  ..$ PDD.Close   : num [1:793] 26.7 24.6 22.5 22.6 20.3 ...
  ..$ PDD.Volume  : num [1:793] 43213200 19923300 13967700 13709600 19339000 ...
  ..$ PDD.Adjusted: num [1:793] 26.7 24.6 22.5 22.6 20.3 ...
 $ RMO :'data.frame':   623 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Index       : Date[1:623], format: "2019-04-01" "2019-04-02" "2019-04-03" "2019-04-04" ...
  ..$ RMO.Open    : num [1:623] 9.8 9.75 9.75 9.76 9.78 9.76 9.76 9.77 9.74 9.74 ...
  ..$ RMO.High    : num [1:623] 9.8 9.75 9.75 9.76 9.78 9.76 9.76 9.77 9.74 9.74 ...
  ..$ RMO.Low     : num [1:623] 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.76 9.75 9.76 9.76 9.77 9.74 9.74 ...
  ..$ RMO.Close   : num [1:623] 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.76 9.75 9.76 9.76 9.77 9.74 9.74 ...
  ..$ RMO.Volume  : num [1:623] 161000 11000 0 1000 100600 ...
  ..$ RMO.Adjusted: num [1:623] 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.76 9.75 9.76 9.76 9.77 9.74 9.74 ...
 $ TSLA:'data.frame':   2826 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Index        : Date[1:2826], format: "2010-06-29" "2010-06-30" "2010-07-01" "2010-07-02" ...
  ..$ TSLA.Open    : num [1:2826] 3.8 5.16 5 4.6 4 ...
  ..$ TSLA.High    : num [1:2826] 5 6.08 5.18 4.62 4 ...
  ..$ TSLA.Low     : num [1:2826] 3.51 4.66 4.05 3.74 3.17 ...
  ..$ TSLA.Close   : num [1:2826] 4.78 4.77 4.39 3.84 3.22 ...
  ..$ TSLA.Volume  : num [1:2826] 93831500 85935500 41094000 25699000 34334500 ...
  ..$ TSLA.Adjusted: num [1:2826] 4.78 4.77 4.39 3.84 3.22 ...
 $ TSM :'data.frame':   3704 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Index       : Date[1:3704], format: "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" ...
  ..$ TSM.Open    : num [1:3704] 11.1 10.9 10.8 10.6 10.8 ...
  ..$ TSM.High    : num [1:3704] 11.1 11 10.8 10.8 10.8 ...
  ..$ TSM.Low     : num [1:3704] 10.8 10.7 10.5 10.6 10.5 ...
  ..$ TSM.Close   : num [1:3704] 10.9 10.9 10.6 10.7 10.6 ...
  ..$ TSM.Volume  : num [1:3704] 12438784 17678653 12691240 5477350 7396096 ...
  ..$ TSM.Adjusted: num [1:3704] 6.38 6.38 6.21 6.25 6.17 ...
```

---

Regarding the `for` loop doesn't do anything issue, 1) it is simply trying to do `fortify.zoo` on the object names and not on the values, 2) even if it is the value on which `fortify.zoo` is applied, it should be assigned back to the original object i.e. if we want to update the original object names, use `assign`

```
for (i in seq_along(xtsObjects)) {
     assign(names(xtsObjects[i]), fortify.zoo(get(names(xtsObjects[i]))))
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and code. However, when applying the ```for``` loop, I get an ```Error in get(xtsObjects[i]) : invalid first argument```. So I modified the code as follows: ```xtsObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts))))``` and the loop ```for (i in 1:length(xtsObjects)) {
  assign(xtsObjects[i], fortify.zoo(get(xtsObjects[i])))
}```. And that did the trick

Comment: @pdeli sorry, i should have wrapped with `names` in the `for` loop updated

Comment: akrun: you mind updating your answer accordingly so I can accept your solution?

Comment: @pdeli I already updated the answer with the `names` i..e `fortify.zoo(get(names(xtsObjects[i]))`  The issue was that `get` was applied on the position index  instead of the actual names and thus resulted in error

Answer (score 0):

Use the `names(which())` and then `lapply`.

```
xtsObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts))))
res <- lapply(mget(xtsObjects), fortify.zoo)
head(res[[1]])
#        Index RMO.Open RMO.High RMO.Low RMO.Close RMO.Volume RMO.Adjusted
# 1 2019-04-01     9.80     9.80    9.75      9.75     161000         9.75
# 2 2019-04-02     9.75     9.75    9.75      9.75      11000         9.75
# 3 2019-04-03     9.75     9.75    9.75      9.75          0         9.75
# 4 2019-04-04     9.76     9.76    9.76      9.76       1000         9.76
# 5 2019-04-05     9.78     9.78    9.75      9.75     100600         9.75
# 6 2019-04-08     9.76     9.76    9.76      9.76      20500         9.76

length(res)
# [1] 4
names(res)
# [1] "RMO"  "TSM"  "TSLA" "PDD"
```

To get the resulting data frames directly into the workspace use `list2env`.

```
list2env(lapply(mget(xtsObjects), fortify.zoo))
ls()  ## list objects currently in workspace
# [1] "PDD"        "RMO"        "tickers"    "TSLA"       "TSM"        "xtsObjects"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your are correct to suggest wrapping ```which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts)))``` in ```names()``` (i.e., ```xtsObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts))))```). However, the rest of your solution puts all the ```xts``` objects into a ```res``` object (a ```list```). What I need is that the discrete ```xts``` objects remain and be converted into ```data.frame``` objects (and remain discrete).

Comment: @pdeli Does `list2env(res)` give you what you want?

Comment: unfortunately not. It gives me this: ```<environment: 0x7febd2b0d518>```. Kindly check out the code I put at the end of my question, then replace the ```for``` loop below the ```# This does not do anything:``` comment with the ```for``` loop suggested by @akrun at the end of the answer and that'll show you what I expected.

Comment: @pdeli `<environment: 0x7febd2b0d518>` is just the console output. Check your environment using `ls()` or `head(PDD)`, the objects should be there! Also see edit.